# Where should I place another language link for a page like wikipedia on mobile

Tags: mobile-application

[image]

Is there is a better suggestion than attached?

Answer (score 1):

Right under the title. I would place a link saying "available in other languages" and on click would send to the bottom of the page where list of languages would be.

It is very annoying when you have to manually scroll somewhere to find a list of languages. Considering the size of the screen I don't see any other position for such link.